# asp.net mvc does not model bind a datetime value although its send with form post

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My form post with fiddler is that:

```
Name=testdate4&CreatedAt=Thu+Jan+01+1970+01%3A00%3A00+GMT%2B0100+(Mitteleurop%C3%A4ische+Zeit)
```

So the CreatedAt date is sent with the hidden field correctly.

But in my action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(TemplateViewModel templateViewModel)
{

}

public class TemplateViewModel
{  
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } 
}
```

The Name is sent and mapped to the Name property but the CreatedAt property is not mapped to the hidden field, why?

Comment: "CreatedAt property is not mapped to the hidden field"??? Are you posting this field through hidden field? Can you show view code?

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue before, and is because my browser accept different date format from the server culture.

For e.g. I set my datepicker in browser to accept dd/mm/yy format but in server default culture is en-US. Even though you manage to see value in fiddler but you can't get it in controller.

So what i do last time is add this to web.config, then everything will work.

< system.web>
    < globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
  < / system.web>

If you like to refer to date sample, [this](http://instinctcoder.com/asp-net-mvc-4-jquery-datepicker-date-format-validation/) may help.